# Django 3 run server error improperly configured on django 3

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-errors

I installed the newest version of Django and when I did the runserver command it showed a really long error. I searched the internet for it but most of the solutions I found were either not working or outdated.

The error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
> Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Please help me as I have been stuck on this for a really long time.

Thanks

Comment: You have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` set in your wsgi.py ...?? and `WSGI_APPLICATION` in settings.py..??

Comment: I have WSGI_APPLICATION in settings.py but no DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in wsgi.py

Comment: your wsgi.py should have this... `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourProject.settings')`

Comment: If it's not there then your project is not created properly...

Comment: I added it in the wsgi.py and did the runserver command again but it shows the same error 

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS
_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: I think some issue while creating project. Create a new project and check if its working.

Comment: also update the question with your setting.py `WSGI_APPLICATION` line and wsgi.py file content.

Comment: Hey, I made a new project and installed django, started the project, did everything you told me to do and ran the server but I am still getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

`wsgi.py` should look like this considering your project name is `yourProject`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourProject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```